# Change UIView Appearance (LTR) When language is Hebrew without restarting app Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

In my App, I have only one language which is Hebrew. I have changed language on Appdelegate in didfinish launch. Now I have only one issue, On app first time launch did not change language and UIView appearance(LTR) When I run second time it have changed whole app language in Hebrew and UIView. I need language change on first time. I have checked too many answers but it has not working. Please let me know if anything for me.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LocalizationSystem:NSObject {
    
    var bundle: Bundle!
    
    class var sharedInstance: LocalizationSystem {
        struct Singleton {
            static let instance: LocalizationSystem = LocalizationSystem()
        }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        bundle = Bundle.main
    }
    
    func localizedStringForKey(key:String, comment:String) -> String {
        return bundle.localizedString(forKey: key, value: comment, table: nil)
    }
    
    func localizedImagePathForImg(imagename:String, type:String) -> String {
        guard let imagePath =  bundle.path(forResource: imagename, ofType: type) else {
            return ""
        }
        return imagePath
    }
    
    //MARK:- setLanguage
    // Sets the desired language of the ones you have.
    // If this function is not called it will use the default OS language.
    // If the language does not exists y returns the default OS language.
    func setLanguage(languageCode:String) {
        var appleLanguages = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! [String]
        appleLanguages.remove(at: 0)
        appleLanguages.insert(languageCode, at: 0)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(appleLanguages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(languageCode, forKey: "languageCode")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() //needs restrat
        
        if let languageDirectoryPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: languageCode, ofType: "lproj")  {
            bundle = Bundle.init(path: languageDirectoryPath)
        } else {
            resetLocalization()
        }
    }
    
    //MARK:- resetLocalization
    //Resets the localization system, so it uses the OS default language.
    func resetLocalization() {
        bundle = Bundle.main
    }
    
    //MARK:- getLanguage
    // Just gets the current setted up language.
    func getLanguage() -> String {
        let appleLanguages = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleLanguages") as! [String]
        let preferredLanguage = appleLanguages[0]
        if preferredLanguage.contains("-") {
            let array = preferredLanguage.components(separatedBy: "-")
            return array[0]
        }
        return preferredLanguage
    }
    
}
```

// Calling in Appdelegate

```
LocalizationSystem.sharedInstance.setLanguage(languageCode: "he")
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Comment: you should have list down the methods you used. otherwise how will others know what you already tried

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Please check this I have list down my methods.

Comment: are you using storyboard or setting root view controller programmatically?

Comment: I have set root viewController  programatically. @AbdulWaheed

Comment: yes. then you need to use DispatchQueue with some delay like 0.5 seconds and then present root view controller. this should solve your problem

Comment: self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVCID") as? LoginVC
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController!)
            self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
:- this is my root Vw..@AbdulWaheed

Comment: put this code in DispatchQueue.main.async(after : .now() + 0.5 ) { your code block}

Comment: this trick is not workings buddy, do you have any other solution for that? @AbdulWaheed

Comment: I think you can use NSNotification Observer option

Comment: do you have any refernce for that? @Jaseel.Dev

Comment: https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/dark-mode-observer-pattern

Comment: instead of theme....u can think it as language...all the best

Comment: have a look at the link and see how it works... i hope that will help you